# dropdown.Items.Clear() not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-select

In my ASP.NET dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubCustomer" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

following code does not clear *items* of drop down before binding data source:

```
dt = obj.subCustomer();
ddlSubCustomer.Items.Clear();
ddlSubCustomer.DataSource = dt;
ddlSubCustomer.DataTextField = "cust_Name";
ddlSubCustomer.DataValueField = "cust_Id";
ddlSubCustomer.DataBind();
```

following is the pictorial representation.

[image]

Please guide me how to for this clear the dropdownlist before binding to the datasource?

Comment: what type of error you got?

Comment: _"it didn't working here"_ means that even if you use this method the `DropDownList`'s `Items` property returns items afterwards before you call `ddlSubCustomer.DataBind`?

Comment: What isn't working? Is the list cleared? is the datasource not changed? does nothing show? Please describe "*didn't working*"

Comment: @PurveshDesai it didn't display an error. It actually bind the data but with a lot off spaces and duplication of data

Comment: @user2504141 that means your data source has duplications.

Comment: Do you really need the `Clear` when you are assigning it a `DataSource`, i believe it would take care of that

Comment: Is `AppendDataBoundItems` set to `true`? What means "a lot of spaces and duplication", have you added static `ListItems` on aspx or programmatically?

Comment: I have updated the question with a pictorial representation

Comment: can you show the code of `subCustomer` method? can't you only select the non empty `cust_Name` containing records as datasource ?

Comment: subCustomer is getting data from the CRM \

Answer (score 1):

try by filter data before set as `DataSource`

```
ddlSubCustomer.DataSource = dt.Select("cust_Name is not null and cust_Name <>''");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ddlSubCustomer.DataSource = null;
```

Before set it to the real source.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            for (int i = ddlSubCustomer.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                ddlSubCustomer.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
```